# Understanding Core Data Queries(searching data for a unique attribute)

Tags: xcode, core-data, one-to-many

Since I am coming from those programmers who have used sqlite extensively, perhaps I am just having a hard time grasping how Core Data manages to-many relationships.

For my game I have a simple database schema on paper.

```
Entity: Level - this will be the table that has all information about each game level

Attributes: levelNumber(String), simply the level number
          : levelTime(String), the amount of time you have to finish the level(this time will vary with the different levels)
          : levelContent(String), a list of items for that level(and that level only) separated by commas
          : levelMapping(String), how the content is layed out(specific for a unique level)
```

So basically in core data i want to set up the database so i can say in my fetchRequest:

> Give me the levelTime, levelContent and levelMapping for Level 1.(or
>   whatever level i want)

How would i set up my relationships so that i can make this type of fetchRequest?
Also I already have all the data ready and know what it is in advance. Is there any way to populate the entity and its attributes within XCode?

Comment: You've only described one entity-- unless you'd somehow make `Level` more than one SQLite table. That entity doesn't seem to relate to itself (there's no `otherLevel` attribute). Am I missing something? What relationship(s) are you thinking might exist?

Comment: well in a normal sqlite database you would have this Level table. This you would add "attributes" that i have described above. I would insert into the table 1, 5:00, someString, someString(in that order according to my post). then i would insert 2, 10:00, someString, someString. Lets say i have 20 levels. I want to be able to query the levelTime, levelContent and levelMapping for any of the level numbers. So in sqlite terms "select levelTime, levelContent, levelMapping from Level where levelNumber is ?(1 - 20). I would rather do this than create 20 different entities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you've described it, it's a single Core Data entity, called `Level` that has four string attributes. Since there's just the one entity, there are no relationships. You'd create the one entity and add properties so that it looks just like you've described it above:

[image]

Getting just one `Level` is basic Core Data fetching:

```
NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Level"];
NSString *levelNumber = @"1";
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"levelNumber = %@", levelNumber];
[request setPredicate:predicate];

NSError *error = nil;
NSArray *results = [[self managedObjectContext] executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
NSManagedObject *level = nil;
if ([results count] > 0) {
    level = [results objectAtIndex:0];
}

// Use level...
```

If it was me I'd use one of the numeric types for `levelNumber`, but maybe you have some reason to use a string there. I'd also probably break `levelContent` into a separate entity, because (a) comma delimited strings are ugly, no matter how you slice 'em, and (b) you might well want the items to have more attributes, and a separate entity would hold those.

Comment: thanks for the info and suggestions Tom. The 2nd part of my question involved pre-populating the database within XCode being that I already know of the data ahead of time? Unless I just am blind i dont see a way..I want to be able to say, 'Okay for level 1 i want the mapping, time and content to be this.. and for level 2.. this and this...etc.

Comment: i guess the other question was is how am i going to link up certain attributes to a certain unique level number? If you cant do it in XCode visually then you have to do it programmatically,

Comment: I don't think I understand the second question. You'd create a new instance of `Level` with whatever attributes it needs, and save the result. Once you look it up you access those attributes via key-value coding. All you're doing is asking an object for an attribute value, same as any other object.

Comment: As for pre-populating the data store, Xcode doesn't help you out there. One option is to have some debug-only code that builds up a data store, and then copy the store file for regular app builds. Another is to use a third-party app like Core Data Editor (in the Mac app store) to enter the data.

Comment: ok thanks for the clarification on the 2nd question. Wonder why Apple didnt allow you to add data from within XCode? I mean they create this great Core Data concept then they leave you hanging it seems where you have to go and do things like download an editor.